# How to see all string objects in visualvm?

Tags: string, java-8, profiling, heap-memory, visualvm

I try to learn how to use java profilers and i choose VisualVM for it.
At this moment i dont understand, how it works for see an objects in a heap.
For example i declare three objects

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!scanner.nextLine().equals("q")) {
        String s1 = "cat";
        String s2 = new String("cat");
        String s3 = new String("cat9");
    }
```

}

So, there is one "cat" in a string pool, "cat" and "cat9" in a heap as String objects.
But when i make heap dump in VisualVM and find all "cat" Strings with

```
select s from java.lang.String s where s.toString().substring(0,3) == "cat"
```

i see onle two objects: "cat" and "cat9".
Wasn't there supposed to be two "cat": one in the string pool, the other in the heap?

Comment: First, all `String` objects are in the heap memory, whether referenced by a pool or not. Then, you are creating four strings, two with the content `"cat"` and two with the content `"cat9"`. Still, this doesn't imply that they will stay in memory. Since you didn't document when and how you created the heap dump, there is not much we can say about it.

Comment: @Holger
I update my code in question.
So, as i planned, all objects should have a reference (and be in heap), while i didnt enter "q".
Heap dump is here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KdIeY_6SYfqWObSahqSx50dZsBT9JPHv/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: So you're taking the heapdump while the program is waiting in `nextLine()`? None of the variables declared in the loop body is in scope at this point of time. But it's worth noting that even local variables in scope do not necessarily prevent the garbage collection of the referenced objects when they are unused.